# pass data through GET parameters without array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I would like to send the data by parameters directly and not the array

The console is returning the data like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVXfz.png)

would like it to be sent like this directly:

ID: 3
Descricao: Executando

Code:
refresh () {
this.$axios.get()

```
     this.$axios.get("/Operacional/GetRelatorio", {
      params: { 
        situacao: this.situacao
      }
     }).then(res => { 
        this.prazos = res.data
        this.$refs.chart1.updateSeries([{
            name: 'NO PRAZO',
            data: [this.prazos.noPrazo, this.prazos.emDia, this.prazos.atrasadas]
         }])
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

params: {
id: your ID,
Descricao: "Executando"
}

Comment: don't I understand? I want to take as parameter only the ID, not the whole array of the object

Comment: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/get-query-params